# Importing data from text file with Timestamp into R

Tags: r, import, timestamp

I have a file with data exported from a database. I find it difficult to make R recognise the Timestamp as date and time. I searched the forum but could not find anything that I can easily enough apply into my file.
No headers in the file. But it is Timestamp and Temperature.
Thanks a lot for your help

The sample data is as follow:
23 January 2015 06:30:00,12.09
23 January 2015 06:35:00,16.29
23 January 2015 06:40:00,14.33
23 January 2015 06:45:00,16.57
23 January 2015 06:50:00,16.29
23 January 2015 06:55:00,14.33
23 January 2015 07:00:00,21.06
23 January 2015 07:05:00,21.06
23 January 2015 07:10:00,13.77
23 January 2015 07:15:00,16.29

Comment: Post some code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- "12.09 23 January 2015 06:35:00,16.29 23 January 2015 06:40:00,14.33 23 January 2015 06:45:00,16.57 23 January 2015 06:50:00,16.29 23 January 2015 06:55:00,14.33 23 January 2015 07:00:00,21.06 23 January 2015 07:05:00,21.06 23 January 2015 07:10:00,13.77 23 January 2015 07:15:00"
dat <- gsub(",", "\n,", dat)
df <- read.csv(textConnection(dat), stringsAsFactors=F, header=F)
df <- df[-1,]
df[,2] <- substring(df[,2], 7, nchar(df[,2]))
df$time <- as.Date(df[,2], format="%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
> df$time
[1] "2015-01-23" "2015-01-23" "2015-01-23" "2015-01-23" "2015-01-23" "2015-01-23"
[7] "2015-01-23" "2015-01-23"
```

Comment: Hi Cory, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it still does not give me proper data structure in df. Running your code gives a column with date only rather date and time (Timestamp). It will be even OK if the date and time are separate in different columns. The main problem is with time as it stays as character type of a factor.

Comment: The df$time is a date object. If you want a character string in a different format, use format().